# How to ignore ResponseWrapper in ASP.NET Core Web API response

Tags: asp.net-core, response, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an web api project in .net core and in Startup there is configured to use a response wrapper "
            app.UseResponseWrapper();"

But this format is applied for all the api methods in my project...

I  want an api method in my solution  that sends another format response , for example a simple xml. I want to know how to ignore that Response wrapper that is applied for all methods? Is there any  decorator for that method ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.
I had built a custom decorator for methods that is able to modify header response.
In the Response wrapper I succeded to manage and to modify the response

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AutoWrapIgnore] filter attribute for endpoints that you don't need to be wrapped.

For example:

```
[HttpGet]
[AutoWrapIgnore]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()  
{
    var data = await _personManager.GetAllAsync();
    return Ok(data);
}
```